# Srping boot Soap Client error when create WebServiceClient Object in Production enviroment

Tags: spring-boot, soap-client

I need to call Soap Client inside a Microservice. It work fine in test enviroment.
When move the app to production enviroment, it cannot make a Soap call because cannot create @WebServiceClient Object  and throw exeption:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at:http://...
```

I was try and find out that, whenever make a soap call, when create @WebServiceClient Object, it's always get the WSDL endpoint again. And now, in production machine, it cannot access the endpoint that in test enviroment.

I don't know why it need to get WSDL again whenever create new Object, How can I bypass this step?
Here is my pom file to genereted WSDL java code:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources-id</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration> 
                            <useCompileClasspath>true</useCompileClasspath> <!-- if you don't use this, the soapui test bundle will cause classloading 
                                issues with this plugin. -->
                            <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates/generated</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>http://xxx?WSDL</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>http://xxx?WSDL</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-all</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Any joy on this? I have the exact same issue, about to rip cxf out and try something else.

Comment: I was use a domain instead of IP for the WSDL url, so it can be use in both dev and production environment.